# Exchange ActiveSync

Tags: activesync

I'm planning to create an application that syncs email, calendars and contacts between Exchange ActiveSync (EAS) and my own database. A few questions:

1. Are there any libraries or wrappers for EAS? (Preferably in Java)
2. What is the licensing cost? Microsoft does not explicitly provide a price anywhere that I've seen.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1)  There are not many sample/libraries available.  Here are your best bets:

- [New to Exchange ActiveSync Development? (MSDN blog)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2011/09/29/new-to-exchange-activesync-development.aspx)
- [Exchange Server Interoperability Guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285606%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx)
- [C# Code sample from MS](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-2010-Implementing-400b9507)
- [Javascript implementation of EAS](https://github.com/mozsquib/jsas)

If you're looking for Java specifically, buried somewhere in the Android mail app, which is open source, will be their EAS implementation which also might be helpful.

(2)  Microsoft does not publish licensing costs and anyone who does license EAS is required to sign an NDA with respect to pricing which is why you will not see any info regarding pricing anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. Do you know if the licensing cost is only for providing ActiveSync mailboxes, or is it also required if you implement ActiveSync in your application?

Comment: My general understanding is that you are required to pay to use any part of ActiveSync - client/server whatever.  From what you briefly described of your app you would be required to license EAS from Microsoft.  To start that process you should contact them:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/IPLicensing/Programs/exchangeactivesyncprotocol.aspx

Comment: The Javascript implementation of EAS link above is for a branch which is 1 commit behind the master. The naster branch is https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/jsas

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best source for implementing a Java library for EAS was the [C# Code Sample from MS](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-2010-Implementing-400b9507).

I converted all the WbXML commands and used a org.w3c.dom for XML parsing and managing the nodes in request and response. Also helpful was pulling the AutoDiscovery code from Microsoft's EWS (Exchange Web Services):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2013/01/03/ews-java-api-1-2-get-started.aspx